# get selected on the last image in Image Gallery

Tags: javascript, file-upload, image-gallery

I use this javascript file to show image gallery but it dose not select the last image that i upload it always select the first image in the gallery

the code in this url
https://github.com/rvera/image-picker/blob/master/image-picker/image-picker.js

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask].   If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor. HERE at Stackoverflow

Comment: Please don't just post a link to 350 lines of code